# createOptionsFromRemotingContext globally

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Is there an option to specify this method globally so it will affect all the models or i need to specify it for every model i want to use it?

```
Customer.createOptionsFromRemotingContext = function(ctx) {
    var base = this.base.createOptionsFromRemotingContext(ctx);
    return extend(base, {
      headers: ctx.req.headers,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with mixins:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-mixins.html

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-mixins